# Bolt CMS - Highlighted only one element from list

Tags: php, bolt-cms

I wish to create news list where only one can be highlighted. Is it possible to create a checkbox field in my contenttype so that checking it for one element, would cause unchecking it for all the others? As a result I need to have only one element checked throughout the whole list.

contenttypes.yml:

```
news:
    name: News
    fields:
        titile:
            type: text
        highlight:
            type: checkbox
```

Comment: Please provide code that you have tried so far.

Comment: ok, thread updated

Comment: Hi can you provide an example of what you want exactly.

Comment: Maybe some expected screenshots.

Comment: I dont know how to explain it more clear - it so simple: only one record can be highlighted for specified contenttype (news). This is controlled by checkbox field named 'highlight'. If user will check this field for more than one record the first one will be automaticly unchecked.

I have sort of news articles and I wish to highlight only one

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to select ONE news item to be highlighted, and only that one item to have highlighted = true (or checked)

Try creating Custom Content Type (call it highlight) using the docs available at https://docs.bolt.cm/3.4/extensions/advanced/fieldtypes
then write some code to do the following:
if "CurrentNewsItem->highlighted" == true then "find all news with highlighted == true & set highlighted to false"

Disclaimer: I'm new to boltcms myself, so there could be a better way to do this that I dont know (yet)